# why wont ubuntu 17.04 launch chrome, spotify, and teamviewer anymore?

Tags: 17.04

I recently upgraded to 17.04 an now i can no longer use some programs. I have un-installed and re-installed and have had no success. I have tried launching form the terminal and it just says:

```
Init...
CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
Launching TeamViewer ...
Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

It just get stuck there. Has anyone encountered this? this is happening to the above mentioned software as well.